# How do I specify a return type for my typed DataStore wrapper function?

Tags: typescript, aws-amplify, datastore

I'm having trouble figuring out what the return type should be for my AWS Amplify DataStore `observeQuery` wrapper function. I have

```js
import { DataStore } from 'aws-amplify'
import type { ProducerModelPredicate } from '@aws-amplify/datastore'
import { TestData } from 'models'

// Configure DataStore etc. ...

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
export const observeTests = (
    description: string,
    criteria?: ProducerModelPredicate<TestData>,
) => {
    const observedQuery = DataStore.observeQuery( TestData, criteria )
    observedQuery.subscribe( ( snapshot ) => {
        // some custom things ...
    } )
    return observedQuery
}
```

which works fine, but our ESLint requirement for an explicit return type is causing a lot of frustration.

I've tried both

```js
Observable<DataStoreSnapshot<TestData>>
```

and

```js
 ReturnType<typeof DataStore.observeQuery<TestData>>
```

But the former requires some deep digging to find the definition of `Observable` (I haven't found it) and the latter is just (unexpectedly?) wrong.

How can I correctly specify a return type for this function?

Comment: Is `TestData` a type or actual data? because I see you using it as both.

Comment: @Harkunwar It's (by Amplify) as `export declare class TestData  ...`

Comment: Not a perfect solution, but does using `ReturnType<typeof DataStore.observeQuery>` fix the ESLint issue?

Comment: @Harkunwar No, that's not the correct return type; `<TestData>` is part of it.